# How to split a string list whose elements are "name-year" based on years in R

Tags: r

I have some codes like this example, if you run these codes

```
library(hurricaneexposure)
library(hurricaneexposuredata)
data("hurr_tracks")
storms <- unique(hurr_tracks$storm_id)
storms
```

then you will see that "storms" has a long string list with "stormname-year" structure.

```
[1] "Alberto-1988"   "Beryl-1988"     "Chris-1988"     "Florence-1988"  "Gilbert-1988"   "Keith-1988"     "Allison-1989"   "Chantal-1989"  
[9] "Hugo-1989"      "Jerry-1989"     "Bertha-1990"    "Marco-1990"     "Ana-1991"       "Bob-1991"       "Fabian-1991"    "Notnamed-1991" 
[17] "Andrew-1992"    "Danielle-1992"  "Earl-1992"      "Arlene-1993"    "Emily-1993"     "Alberto-1994"   "Beryl-1994"     "Gordon-1994"   
[25] "Allison-1995"   "Dean-1995"      "Erin-1995"      "Gabrielle-1995" "Jerry-1995"     "Opal-1995"      "Arthur-1996"    "Bertha-1996"   
[33] "Edouard-1996"   "Fran-1996"      "Josephine-1996" "Subtrop-1997"   "Ana-1997"       "Danny-1997"     "Bonnie-1998"    "Charley-1998"  
[41] "Earl-1998"      "Frances-1998"   "Georges-1998"   "Hermine-1998"   "Mitch-1998"     "Bret-1999"      "Dennis-1999"    "Floyd-1999"    
[49] "Harvey-1999"    "Irene-1999"     "Beryl-2000"     "Gordon-2000"    "Helene-2000"    "Leslie-2000"    "Allison-2001"   "Barry-2001"
```

My question is how to split these elements based on same year. For example, I want to create a new variable "y1988" which is a list that has all storms in 1998. If I run y1988, it will output:

```
y1988
[1] "Alberto-1988"   "Beryl-1988"     "Chris-1988"     "Florence-1988"  "Gilbert-1988"   "Keith-1988"
```

So as for y1989 until 2001. I am guessing it might use gsub() and a for-loop，however, I am a rookie in R, so really hope you could give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` with grouping variable created by removing the prefix substring including the `-` with `sub`.

```
lst <- split(storms, sub(".*-", "", storms))
lst$`1988`
#[1] "Alberto-1988"  "Beryl-1988"    "Chris-1988"    "Florence-1988"
#[5] "Gilbert-1988"  "Keith-1988"
```

#### data

```
storms <- c("Alberto-1988", "Beryl-1988", "Chris-1988", "Florence-1988", 
 "Gilbert-1988", "Keith-1988", "Allison-1989", "Chantal-1989", 
 "Hugo-1989", "Jerry-1989", "Bertha-1990", "Marco-1990", "Ana-1991", 
 "Bob-1991", "Fabian-1991", "Notnamed-1991", "Andrew-1992", "Danielle-1992", 
 "Earl-1992", "Arlene-1993", "Emily-1993", "Alberto-1994", "Beryl-1994", 
 "Gordon-1994", "Allison-1995", "Dean-1995", "Erin-1995", "Gabrielle-1995", 
 "Jerry-1995", "Opal-1995", "Arthur-1996", "Bertha-1996", "Edouard-1996", 
 "Fran-1996", "Josephine-1996", "Subtrop-1997", "Ana-1997", "Danny-1997", 
 "Bonnie-1998", "Charley-1998", "Earl-1998", "Frances-1998", "Georges-1998", 
 "Hermine-1998", "Mitch-1998", "Bret-1999", "Dennis-1999", "Floyd-1999", 
 "Harvey-1999", "Irene-1999", "Beryl-2000", "Gordon-2000", "Helene-2000", 
 "Leslie-2000", "Allison-2001", "Barry-2001")
```

Comment: Awesome! This helps me a lot. By the way, I try gsub(".+-","", storms) also works fine in this case. So I am confused about gsub() and sub(), what is the difference with a real example?

Comment: you don't have to split, with `sub` you simply choose the part of the string you want to use: `sub(".*-(.*)","\\1", storms)`

Comment: @MarkusN Yes, that is possible, but I guess the OP was looking for a general way.

Comment: @BrattSwan  With `gsub` it will substitute for more than one occurence.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extract the year directly within your original dataframe? libraries `dplyr` and `tidyr` are well suited for problems like this.
I suggest the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
hurr_tracks %>%
    extract(storm_id, c("storm", "year"),"(.+)-(.+)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way using stringr

> split(storms,str_extract(storms,"[0-9]+"))